# Different AutoNumbers to specific selection

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need some vba help at my Access project.

In our company we got different construction sites.
Each construction site have their own cost centre.
We have to make reports to each construction sites related to the cost centre.
These reports have their own continious number(related to the cost centres)

I got a formular, where I can choose the cost centre and want to be shown the latest report number +1, when making a new input, so no mistakes can happen for users.

[Formular looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YixxQ.png)

**Nr.** is related to the textfield *Nummer* with the content *raumBTBNR* for the increasing Report numbers. **Kostenstelle** got the combo box called *KostenstelleAuswahl* with the content *raeumKostenstelleIDRef* for the cost centres.

Code so far: *(credits by Gustav)*

```
Private Sub Nummer_GotFocus()
Dim NextNumber As Long

                   highest Rep.Nr.        related table      Content of KostenstelleAuswahl
NextNumber = DMax("[raumBTBNR]",        "[tbl_Raeumstellen]", "[KostenstellenIDRef] = " & Me!KostenstelleAuswahl.Value & "") + 1
Me!Nummer = NextNumber

End Sub
```

My solution right now is a  [query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfCcM.png), where i count the number of the reports, related to the cost centres. But it does not fill automatically and is more worse than nice. **Which is saved at MaxNr**
[Example in my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44Unh.png)

I would appreciate some help!:)

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: updated. sorry!

Comment: When you say "no mistakes can happen for users" do you mean that you want to provide them with the next sequential number so they don't have to figure it out and enter it for themselves? If so, and if you are using Access_2010 or later, then you should be able to use an event-driven Data Macro to automatically assign the next sequential number when the row is added to the table, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35947449/2144390).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, then this should work - when selecting Kostenstelle:

```
Private Sub KostenstelleAuswahl_AfterUpdate()

    Dim NextNumber As Long

    NextNumber = DMax("[raumBTBNR]", "[tbl_Raeumstellen]", "[raeumKostenstelleIDRef] = " & Me!KostenstelleAuswahl.Value & "") + 1

    Me!Nr.Value = NextNumber

End Sub
```

Comment: _"Runtime Error '9' - Invalid use of Null._                                                         `Private Sub Nummer_GotFocus()
Dim NextNumber As Long

    NextNumber = DMax("[AuftrIDRef]", "[tbl_Raeumstellen]", "[raumBTBNr] = " & Me!AuftrIDRef.Value & "") + 1
    Me!Nummer = NextNumber 

End Sub ` -------- **AuftrIDRef** = field of cost centre number  |  **tbl_Rauemstellen** = source of datas | **raumBTBNR** = Report number | **Me!AuftrIDRef** = Field of cost centre number | **Nummer** = Fieldname of ReportNumber

Comment: Sounds like `Me!AuftrIDRef` is empty (_Null_).

Comment: Okay i renamed some fields so you can understand it more easy. If you take a look at my pic(1st post): **Nr.** is related to the textfield _Nummer_ with the content _raumBTBNR_ for the increasing Report numbers. **Kostenstelle** got the combo box called _KostenstelleAuswahl_ with the content _raeumKostenstelleIDRef_ for the cost centres. I tried every possibility at ur code but i finally dont get it.  **EDIT**: Any mistake is still there.. I mean.. raumBTBNr has to be empty(Null), but not the cost centre..

Comment: But on the picture, there is also a MaxNummer, another combobox. Not easy to follow. You should edit your question to include all details.

Comment: My mistake was, that raumBTBNr was declared as bigint... not long . I am very sorry! Now working