# New record only, when subform has records

Tags: ms-access, vba

Five month ago, I got help with this problem:
[Auto next number count to specific selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52381733/different-autonumbers-to-specific-selection)

I needed this auto count for daily reports at constuction sites.
Now my Problem is, the code

```
Dim NextNumber As Long
NextNumber = Nz(DMax("[raumBTBNR]", "[tbl_RaeumstellenErfassung]", "[raeumKostenstelleIDRef] = " & Me!KostenstelleAuswahl.Value & ""), 0) + 1
Me!Nummer = NextNumber
```

is placed at *SelectingCostCentre_AfterUpdate*  ( Its working correctly )

The consequence:
If an employee wants to write the daily report:
He opens the program, selects the matching construction site he is at and the daily report number counts +1. So far so good...
If he is now leaving the program, or is clicking at another form **without**
adding employees at the activity form, Access saved the record in spite of this.
When he now wants to enter the record again, he has to type in his construction site again, but the auto report number isn't correct anymore, because he counts +1 again. This relates to an *DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec* at *Form_Open*

[Form looks like this](http://i.epvpimg.com/SQQTfab.png)

What i want access to do is:

```
When opening the form, check if the last record (of the specific constr. site) at table 
"Constructionsite entry" has entries at the table "activity log"
If True 
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
Else 
    Open Last Record of the matching constuction site
```

**EDIT:**
or something like:

```
If no data entries at table "activity log" available
Recordset current delete
```

Apparently my VBA skills are very basic .. if any.
I looked at function DLookup, but don't know how to handle syntax with this type of problem.

**EDIT2**
Got a first step of a Solution:

```
If DCount("*", "tbl_RaeumstellEnerfassung", _
          "RaeumKostenstelleIDRef=" & Me!KostenstelleAuswahl & " " & _
               "AND raeumDatum =" & Format(Me!raeumDatum, _
                                       "\#yyyy-mm-dd\#")) > 1 Then
                If MsgBox("Die Räumstelle " & Me![KostenstelleAuswahl].Column(1) & " ist am  " & Me![raeumDatum] & " schon eingetragen worden!" & vbCrLf & "Trotzdem fortfahren?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) = vbNo Then
         DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acLast
         DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdDeleteRecord
DoCmd.SetWarnings True
      Else
         Cancel = False
    End If
    End If
```

He checks if a constructionsitenumber and a date is already entered.
What I would like to do is having a third MsgBox button as Dlookup or DLast, which shows me the last data related to this construction site.

```
DLookup("[raeumID]", "tbl_RaeumstellenErfassung", "[KostenstellenIDRef] ="Forms![frm_RaeumstellenErfassung]![KostenstellenAuswahl]")
```

apperently this isnt working .. more precisly I dont get this to work with a 3d button

Comment: What would be the search criteria to look for record in 'activity log' -  construction site on specific date?

Comment: Construction site has a "raeumstellenNummer"  as  auto number. The  "activity log"  table takes over this value as "raeumstellenNummerRef".

Comment: And where is that number so it can be referred to? Is it still displayed on form?

Comment: Idk what exactly you mean honestly... The raeumstellenNummer or raeumstellenNummerRef aren't shown at the form.

Comment: Maybe now I know what you mean. If its neccassary I can display the "raeumstellenNummer"(table constr. site) and "raeumstellenNummerRef"(table activity log) too. its the most unique criteria and used for referential integrity at my database . If not, its the "construction site ref" &  "activityDate" at table "activity log"

Comment: Really not enough info to advise specific code. If you need to determine if a record was already created when user returns to form, then need criteria to search with. One approach may be to search for the construction site and a date if there should be only one entry per site per date. Another may be to save the new ID to a global variable as soon as record is initiated so it can be referenced when returning to form. Many ways to accomplish depending on work flow.

Comment: I think ur 1st way with the criteria would be a nice solution. What Infos do you exactly need to know to give a specific solution?

Comment: You say user might click another form then return to activity form so the activity form never closes? Just clicking another form should not cause the new record edit to commit to table. Should be able to return to form and continue edit. So I just don't understand your work flow and form designs well enough. Maybe you should prevent leaving form without either data input or user confirming they want to quit the data entry. Maybe they shouldn't be able to 'click another form'.

Comment: Well at least he dont have to change the form, its enought when he leaves the programm. Leaving the form without saving is not possible, because the Construction site table has the Data: AutoNumber, Date, ConstrSiteNr., Report Number.  Activity Log table is in a relation with the AutoNumber of const.site, thats the thing.... When a user enters a constructionsite number its immediatly saved. Maybe you can move this discussion to a chat? I cant.. to less reputation. could show you some more pics or a video then.

Comment: @June7 did an Edit

Comment: Or you can go to a forum site that allows attaching files. Don't put variables within quote marks, concatenate variables. Reference to control is a variable. `"[KostenstellenIDRef] =" & Forms!…)`