# Get last entry in an access DB table programatically?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I am creating customer records and want to use a customised ID based on year and the number +1 of last data row in my Access DB table.

Example ID would be year and next vacant row row number where the new data would be written.(if it is a new DB table would be 2019-0001)

I have worked out how to extract the year from the date, but I can't find any information for getting the number of records in an Access DB table, any pointers where to find information/code would be helpful.

I've used the normal CRUD methods to enter data, but I'd like the Customer ID to be filterable by year (first 4 digits) so it can be used to create a loyalty bonus type reward system.

Comment: Do you really need to *store* the ID like that, or just *display* the ID like that?  I suspect an `INTEGER` column for the year and an `AUTOINCREMENT` column for the number would be simpler.  Then simply format them as needed when you display them.

Comment: An autonumber field increments itself and is the best thing to use for this, is there a reason you don't want to use one?  Among other things it will prevent the problem of 2 queries collecting and using the same row count at the same time.  You can use a calculated-field to format the autonumber with the date.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses, but I am trying to avoid auto increment because I have to do joins etc to display. If I create the index from start, it makes the searching/display easier. There will only be 1 user allowed access to the DB create custID, so I don't see the duplication issue happening.

Comment: As this table will be used for multiple year records, the auto increment could start the first member of year 2020, as a high number, which doesn't make sense, I want it to start at 1.

Comment: @MintedDave: In that case I guess you'd create an ID by selecting from the table, adding one, and inserting into the table.  As long as you can guarantee that this will only ever be a single-user system so as to avoid race conditions, that should work.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: Generating custom unique identifier is a common topic. Perhaps the following will give you ideas and can adapt to C# http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=23329 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947449/create-sequential-id-value-based-on-the-year-that-a-record-is-added

Answer (score 0):

I just implemented a similar ID in one of my organization's databases. The key is to maintain two separate columns, one for the year and one for the ID. You can use the two columns as your primary key as well to maintain integrity, although I found it was easier to use a separate autonumber column as the primary key.

You can use a query similar to the following to add records sequentially for each year. It uses the `Nz` function to check for nulls (i.e. new year) and defaults Id to 0 and then adds 1.

```
INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE (Year, Id)
SELECT New_Year, New_Id 
FROM (SELECT 2019 as New_Year, Nz(Max(Id),0)+1 as New_Id FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Year = 2019);
```

You will need to use the `Format` function in your SELECT queries and forms/reports to display it in the format `####-####`, since leading zeros won't be stored and aren't necessary in the raw data.

Below is an example of a SELECT query that prints the composite IDs

```
SELECT Format([Year],"0000") & "-" & Format([Id],"0000") AS Composite_Id
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was going to do it that way, but want to see if it could be done without hard coding search queries that will have to be changed each year. Text IDs seemed to be easier to use and update than using composite Ids. I am experimenting with bound data, rather than using SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Well composite IDs are a bit of a headache in Access...the solution i have used over the years is to have my ID as a Autonumber/Primary key and create a composite key just for display purposes.
One solution is to create a Table that holds all the years along with the last entry
2017 1232
2018 2122
2019 2001
So each time you want to add a new entry you read the current year...if is a match you read the last value...you add it to the composite key field like 2019002001 and you increment the last entry value by 1
2019 2002

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all those who have taken time to answer my question.

What I was looking for was simple line(s) of C# code to find the last entry in an Access database table. SQL query isn't the problem, or the answer I was looking for. (Why use stored procedures in a C# program if you don't need to?)

I have decided to do it in datasets instead of just querying the Access DB table for the last entry, something I wanted to avoid.