# How do I reset numbering on an Access subform when a new master record is added?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Having not looked at an Access db for about a decade, I find myself in need of a simple VBA (or best method) solution.

I have created a master form with two subforms.

The master form (frmProjectData) contains an autonumber ID field.  It houses the primary key.

The subforms (frmFeatData and frmFutuireFeatData) are linked to the primary key via dummy (non-visible) number fields.  Each subform also contains an autonumber field (not linked) that numbers each subrecord as it is entered.

The forms seem to work well together, with both subforms capturing as many records as needed and tying them to their appropriate master record.  I would like to have the subforms restart numbering at 1 each time a new blank master record is opened.  I recall bits and pieces of code, but nothing I've tried seems to be working so far.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Generating custom identifier is a common topic. You would need to have another field and populate it using VBA code. Alternative is to calculate this sequential number when needed. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ranking.html

Comment: Actually, there is a way to populate the field by use of DMax() domain aggregate function in DefaultValue property and no VBA involved. Be aware that in a multi-user db there is risk of multiple users generating the same value regardless of method of generating and saving value. Minimizing that possibility is tricky.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970466/2144390

Comment: Several way to do this. Numbering can be automatic or determined (priority) by the user. Study my article and full code at [VBA.RowNumbers](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.RowNumbers).