# Generate next free number in specific sequence

Tags: ms-access, dependencies, sequence, auto-generate

I am tranfering a lot of data to Access instead of excel.
I need to get this tool to generate the next free number for my tools.

The number depents on two things, the

1. Type of tool (Flare, Expander...)
2. Work area (20002, 20003)

If it is a Flare it starts with "98" next number is from witch area it is used, so if it is used in 20002 the number is "982" and the last 2 digits it next free number. Have all the tools in a table.
How can i get it to figure this out.
The point is you choose Type of tool and then Station and then it should generate the number and put it in Nummer[image: Tool Form]

Sorry it is for a danish company to the text is in danish. :)

Is this posible? Are is it to hardcore for a newbee.

Got it to work in Excel, in VBA there i had to seperate the tools in different sheets to get it to work.

Have tried it in excel, and tried the same code in Access, but don't work.
I am a newbee in Access so bare with me.

Comment: Neither _Commentar_ nor _Besrkivelse_ are Danish. The last is a typo, but still ...

Answer (score 0):

Look up the last used number:

```vb
TypeNumber = 98
WorkNumber = 20002

MainNumber = TypeNumber * 10 + (WorkNumber Mod 10) 
LastNumber = Nz(DLookup("[Nummer]", "[NummerTabel]", "[Nummer] \ 100 = " & MainNumber & ""), 0) Mod 100
NextNumber = MainNumber * 100 + LastNumber + 1
```

Comment: An alternative solution that does not rely on VBA would be to use an event-driven data macro. The approach would be similar to the one presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35970466/2144390).